# Next.js fetch data when clicking a button

Tags: next.js, caching, fetch, server-side-rendering

I have a server component that fetches data and passes it to child components via props. The issue is that when I refresh the page, the data doesn't update; it's as if it's still cached.

That's why I want to have a button to manually fetch the data again, but I don't know how to do it because the data is passed from the server component to the child components.

Therefore, the data should always be obtained from the main page, but I can't use client components for two reasons:

1- because I want to take advantage of the benefits of server components, and making the main page client-side would mean that all child components would also be client-side.

2- the APIs from which I am fetching data exclusively require the fetch to be done from a backend, which is why I am using next.js to fetch from a server component.

Im using `Next.js 14.1.2`, the function getSummoner comes from a `.js` file, which does all the fetching and js logic

this is my code:

```js
import getSummoner from "@/js/getSummoner";

const Summoner = async ({ params }) => {
  const search = params.search;

  let summoner = await getSummoner(search);

  if (summoner) {

    return (
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center gap-2 mb-2">
        <UpdateButton /> // This button should fetch the data again when clicked

        // Other components that use the summoner data
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either set `dynamic = 'force-dynamic'` or `revalidate = 0` in the page route like so

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

// or

export const revalidate = 0
```

This will skip the Full Route Cache and the Data Cache. Meaning components will be rendered and data fetched on every incoming request to the server, read more [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#opting-out-2)